# Yang Mills Full Form Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conventions, lie-algebra, yang-mills

I am trying to derive the full form of the Yang-Mills Lagrangian(which should have been straightforward). I started from
$$
L= -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}_aF_{\mu\nu}^a
$$
which gives
$$
L = -\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu A^a_\nu\partial^\mu A_a^\nu+g\partial_\mu A_\nu^a f_a^{bc}A^\mu_b A^\nu_c +\text{4-vertex term}.
$$

For the moment I am only concerned with the 3-vertex term. I am trying to show that it is equal to $2igTr(\partial_\mu A_\nu[A^\mu,A^\nu])$. Now I know that I have to use the convention that $Tr(T^a,T^b)=\frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}$ and the commutation relations of the algebra
$$
[T^a,T^b]=if^{ab}_cT^c
$$
where $T^i$s are the generators of the $SU(N)$. How can I bring my second term into the Trace form? (Note that I have done this for the kinetic/first term)

Comment: I don't understand your approach. You have $L$ as a trace, then you express it without the trace, and then you re-express it with a trace? Isn't it simpler to just use the definition of $F$ inside the trace?

Comment: Correct, I have made the edits needed. I basically want to derive both forms of the Lagrangian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YM Lagrangian is
$$
{\cal L} = - \frac{1}{2} \text{tr} [ F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} ], \qquad F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu + i g [ A_\mu, A_\nu ] . 
$$
Expanding it out,
$$
{\cal L} =   - \frac{1}{2} \text{tr} [ ( \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu )^2 ] - 2 i g \text{tr} [ \partial_\mu A_\nu  [ A^\mu, A^\nu ] ] + \frac{g^2}{2} \text{tr} [ [ A_\mu, A_\nu ]^2 ]
$$
Expanding the trace out in the cubic term, we have
\begin{align}
- 2 i g \text{tr} [ \partial_\mu A_\nu  [ A^\mu, A^\nu ] ] &= - 2 i g  \partial_\mu A^a_\nu A^{b\mu} A^{c\nu} \text{tr} [ T^a [ T^b , T^c  ]  ] \\
&= - 2 i g  \partial_\mu A^a_\nu A^{b\mu} A^{c\nu} i f^{bcd} \text{tr} [ T^a T^d ]\\
&= 2 g f^{bcd} \partial_\mu A^a_\nu A^{b\mu} A^{c\nu} \frac{1}{2} \delta^{ad} \\
&= g f^{abc} \partial_\mu A^a_\nu A^{b\mu} A^{c\nu}  
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, I had actually carried on with the derivation and if one starts with expanding inside the trace then both representations are seen clearly. Just a small note, your last term (quartic) would that be equal to $g^2Tr(A_\mu A_\nu[A^\mu,A^\nu])$?

Comment: There's a factor of $-1/2$ in the Lagrangian itself right?

Comment: Yes but if I'd like to use $[A_\mu,A_\nu][A^\mu,A^\nu]=2A_\mu A_\nu [A^\mu,A^\nu]$ then my term would be correct? I'd just like to confirm that this is true.

Comment: Oh, I missed that fact that you removed a bracket. Yes indeed, you are correct. However, it is not a good thing to do. The term is much easier to simplify if you keep the brackets.