# Explicit formula Yang-Mills Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, yang-mills

I'm reading **Hamilton's book Mathematical Gauge Theory** and here in page $415$ we have

The local field strenght is given by

$$ (F^A)^a_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_v A^a_\mu +f_{a b c} A^b_\mu A^c_\nu $$

with structural constant defined by

$$[T_a,T_b]=\sum_{c=1}^r f_{a b c}T_c\quad \text{where $\{T_c\}$ is the base of the Lie Algebra $\mathfrak g$} $$

the YM-Lagrangian is
$$ \mathcal L_{YM}[A]=-\frac{1}{4}(F^A)^a_{\mu \nu}(F^A)_a^{\mu \nu}$$

$$ =-\frac{1}{4}(\partial_\mu A^a_\nu -\partial\nu A^a_\mu)(\partial^\mu A^\nu_a - \partial^\nu A^\mu_a)$$

$$\quad -\frac{1}{2}f_{a b c}(\partial_\mu A^a_\nu -\partial_\nu A^a_\mu)A^{b \mu} A^{c \nu}$$

$$-\frac{1}{4} f_{a b c} f_{a d e} A^b_\mu A^c_{\nu} A^{d \mu} A^{e \nu} $$

I tried to write down this by hand, but **I don't know what to do in order to obtain those two last terms in this expression.** I'd appreciate any help !

- remark: I find out this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/693035/)  but they use trace formula and I'd like to use only the given structure equation for the curvature.

**complement: what I did**

as $A\in \Lambda^1(U; \mathfrak g)$ we have$A_\mu=A_\mu^k T_k$ so
\begin{equation*}
    [A_\mu,A_\nu]=[A_\mu^b T_b,A_\nu^c T_c]=A_\mu^b A_\nu^c [T_b, T_c]= A_\mu^b A_\nu^c f^a_{b c}\; T_a
\end{equation*}
where the structural constants are
\begin{equation*}
    [T_a,T_b]=\sum_{c=1}^r f_{a b}^cT_c\
\end{equation*}
so we have that
\begin{align*}
    (F^A)_{\mu \nu}^a T_a&=\partial_\mu (A^a_\nu T_a) - \partial_v (A^a_\mu T_a) + A_\mu^b A_\nu^c f^a_{b c}\; T_a\\
     &=\left(\partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_v A^a_\mu +f_{b c}^a A^b_\mu A^c_\nu\right) T_a
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    (F^A)^{\sigma \lambda}_k T^k= (\partial^\sigma A^\lambda_k - \partial^\lambda A^\sigma_k+ f^{m n}_k A^\sigma_m A^\lambda_n)T^k
\end{equation*}
finally we have that
\begin{align*}
    (F^A)^a_{\mu \nu}(F^A)^{\sigma \lambda}_k=&(\partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_v A^a_\mu)(\partial^\sigma A^\lambda_k - \partial^\lambda A^\sigma_k)\\
    &+(\partial^\sigma A^\lambda_k - \partial^\lambda A^\sigma_k)f^a_{b c} A_\mu^b A_\nu^c + (\partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_v A^a_\mu) f^{m n}_k A^\sigma_m A^\lambda_n\\
    &+ f^a_{b c} f^{m n}_kA_\mu^b A_\nu^c A^\sigma_m A^\lambda_n
\end{align*}
implying that
\begin{align*}
    (F^A)^a_{\mu \nu}(F^A)^{\mu \nu}_a=&(\partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_v A^a_\mu)(\partial^\mu A^\nu_a - \partial^\nu A^\mu_a)\\
    &+(\partial^\mu A^\nu_a - \partial^\nu A^\mu_a)f^a_{b c} A_\mu^b A_\nu^c + (\partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_v A^a_\mu) f^{b c}_a A^\mu_b A^\nu_c\\
    &+ f^a_{b c} f^{d e}_a A_\mu^b A_\nu^c A^\mu_d A^\nu_e
\end{align*}

If what I did was correct, the first and third line are ok, but I don't know what to do for the second one to get the term

$$-\frac{1}{2}f_{a b c}(\partial_\mu A^a_\nu -\partial_\nu A^a_\mu)A^{b \mu} A^{c \nu} $$

Comment: You have various index problems. All indices in the next-to-final expression must be contracted.

Comment: sorry it was a typo. the final expression is the book expression. the next-to-final expression was my attempt.

Comment: since I'm contracting all indices in those two terms in the penultimate line of my attempt, can I say that they are equal?

Comment: Yes, since the same pairs are getting contracted. If you’re concerned about Lie index placement (i.e., up vs. down) then you have issues beginning with your very first equation where three $a$’s are up and one is down.

Comment: Got it! Since those terms are equal we have all terms that appears in Hamilton's book. and yep, I agree with with respect to index in the very first equation, seems wrong (or at best, not a good choice since we're using Einstein summation all the way)